# I can not get data from the data function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the data returned by the date for use in and if I'm not getting

```
$('input[name=next1]').click(function() {
    var array = formulario.serializeArray();

    if(array[0].value == '' || array[1].value == '') {
        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Preencha todos os dados da primeira etapa, para poder ir para a segunda etapa!</p></div>');
    } else {
        $.get('validare.php?email=' + array[0].value, function(data) {                                          
            var dados = data;
        });

        if(dados == 0) {
            $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>E-mail já existe!</p></div>');                                   
        } else {
            $('.resp').html('');
            next($(this));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oi Leandro, recomendo dar uma olhada nesse link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation

Answer (score 0):

$.get is asynchronous call so dados will be assigned when ajax call will return. You should put your code in callback:

```
$.get('validare.php?email=' + array[0].value,function(data){                                            
    var dados = data;
    if(dados == 0) {
        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>E-mail já existe!</p</div>');
    } else {
        $('.resp').html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: I did it, but this way the next () function; It does not work properly. She would have to go to the next fieldset the form, but will not.